# How do I reactively subscribe to something based on user info in Meteor with React?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm having a huge problem with `Meteor.user()`, especially (I believe) since I'm running with server side rendering.

I want to subscribe to something based on the user's email, but I don't know how. Here's how I normally subscribe:

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({


    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getMeteorData() {
        let data = {}
        let handle = Meteor.subscribe('keypairs', this.props._id)
        if (handle.ready()) {
            data.keypair = KeyPairs.findOne()
            // I add data.currentUser = Meteor.user() here if I need it later
        }
    },
})
```

But what do I do if I want to subscribe to something based on `Meteor.user()`, i.e. `let handle = Meteor.subscribe('keypairs', Meteor.user().emails[0].address)` (will not work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should never](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/securing-meteor-call/#tmc-never-send-the-current-users-_id) pass user information from the client to a method or subscription since the server already knows who the user is!

Just do:

```
Meteor.subscribe('keypairs');
```

And on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('keypairs',function(){
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if ( user ){
    const email = user.emails[0].address;
    ... do your thing
    return Keypairs.find(query,options);
  }
  this.ready();
});
```